# Have any nations that are not UNCLOS members stated plans to start mining in international waters?

Tags: international-law

Deep Sea mining in international waters is regulated by the 1982 [United Nations Convention on the Law of the Sea](https://www.un.org/Depts/los/convention_agreements/convention_overview_convention.htm) (UNCLOS). The convention has been ratified by 167 state parties, excluding the US and several other nations.

[image: Member (blue) and observer (gold) states of the International Seabed Authority]

*Member (blue) and observer (gold) states of the International Seabed Authority.* [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:InternationalSeabedAuthority-members.png)

Have any non-signatory nations announced plans to proceed with mining within international waters?

Comment: While I welcome the question, it might make sense to differentiate clearly between **mining** and **drilling for oil**. The latter is the reason why most states at the [Kaspian sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caspian_Sea#Territorial_status) have not joined UNCLOS: it defines large parts of the Kaspian sea as "high sea" and thus not national territory. The states maintain it is just a large lake, and every square mile should be part of a national territory, bringing exploitation of its oil resources under their control.